# how use SCTP_nodelay in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, sctp

I'm trying to use sctp_nodelay but it seems not possible in python. I looked for an exemple in the internet but only tcp_nodelay found. Someone has an idea ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work out of the box by setting `.nodelay` to `True` on the socket:

```
from sctp import sctpsocket_tcp

sock = sctpsocket_tcp(socket.AF_INET)
sock.nodelay = True
```